# Batch Script - Dir file list into variables, then run loop with exe for each file

Tags: list, variables, batch-file

I'm having trouble figuring this out, but here is the whole scenario:

I have a bunch of FLV files that have meta information encoded in them. I have a small program (flvmeta.exe) that works from command line that turns that meta data into text, and I can export that data to a text file.

I need to figure out how make this happen:
The user will input a path to a directory, and the batch file should CD into that directory.

```
set /p PATH= Enter Path:
CD /D %PATH%
```

Then I need a way to list the file names without header info, like:

```
dir /b /a-d
```

Then I need to make all list items from the dir command into separate variables This is the part I'm having trouble with. (There may be a better way, such as a loop that goes from one file to the next)

...and then I need to execute this command on each file:

```
flvmeta.exe filename.flv >filename.txt
```

So, like I said, a loop may be better for something like this, rather than trying to create variable names from files after a dir command. I'm not very skilled in the command line, or with batch scripting, so forgive me if I'm missing a simple solution.

I have hundreds of these files to go through, and they are in different directories. That is why I'm looking to make this automated with a batch file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: using your own `PATH` variable is a bad idea.It will collide with the built-in path variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p "mypath=Enter Path: "
for %%i in ("%mypath%\*.flv") do flvmeta.exe "%%i" >"%%~dpni.txt"
```

for the expression `%%~dpni` see `for /?`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /p "_PATH= Enter Path:"
set flvmeta=c:\flvmeta.exe

pushd %_PATH%

for "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.flv') do (
   %flvmeta% "%%~fa" > "%%~na.txt"
)
```

if you wish you can add `/s` to dir command for recursive search.